# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'registration' in 'where clause' in Yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

```
$use = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('name')
        ->from('user','registration')
        ->where('user.id=registration.user_id')
        ->queryRow();
```

If I unload MySQL with cmd, this command goes
in Yii I was confused, I tried to change but it was still wrong.

Comment: it's     ->where('user.id=registration.user_id')

Comment: I think you should look at https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#join()-detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the old school pre ANSI-92 implicit join syntax, and I'm not sure that Yii supports that.  Intsead, try using the modern explicit join syntax:

```
$use= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('u.name')
    ->from('user u')
    ->join('registration r', 'u.id = r.user_id')
    ->queryRow();
```

Comment: what if I add a place with user.id = "1"
it's like  ->where('user.id = 1')

Comment: @kagami Yes, I think you can use `->where('u.id = 1')` in this case, because we have defined an alias earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You should use array if you want to pass multiple tables to [`from()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#from()-detail).

```
$use = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('name')
    ->from(['user', 'registration'])
    ->where('user.id=registration.user_id')
    ->queryRow();
```

Alternatively you could pass them as string:

```
$use = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('name')
    ->from('user, registration')
    ->where('user.id=registration.user_id')
    ->queryRow();
```